# Addressing multiple DOM elements for bootstrap tooltip and popover

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to address two attributes to trigger to popover and tooltip activation for bootstrap. Is this the correct way to do it? I don't want to repeat the code twice unless there is simply no other way. If anyone can advise.

```
        // activate tooltips
        $("[rel=tooltip], [data-rel=tooltip]").tooltip();

        // activate popovers
        $("[rel=popover], [data-rel=tooltip]").popover();
```

I also tried the following:

```
        // activate tooltips
        $("[rel=tooltip]" , "[data-rel=tooltip]").tooltip();

        // activate popovers
        $("[rel=popover]" , "[data-rel=tooltip]").popover();
```

Comment: You may need to specify the element tag too e.g. `$("div[rel=tooltip], div[data-rel=tooltip]").tooltip();`. It may work with `*` instead of `div`.

Comment: Its already working without the div and with single reference, I don't see why I need to add a div to it...

Comment: I assumed it wasn't working. If it's working, why are you asking?

Comment: please read the question again, if you do not understand please don't try to answer.

Comment: You have a **tooltip** selector in your **popover()** call.

Comment: Thats it! Silly me!!!